# angularfire auth function to verify if email is in use

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, firebase-authentication

I know that android angularfire provide something along the line of firebase.auth.getinstances() which could fetch and check whether or not any email identifier matches with the input field to validate the email availability. Is there an equivalant function for web app as I've been looking for the documentation without avail.

this is what i have so far, what i want to achieve is to be able to validate the email before proceeding to let user key in a password

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="SignupForm">
  <div *ngIf="!regEmail">
    <div class="form-group w-100">
      <button mat-button type="button" class="btn-google" (click)="authService.GoogleAuth()">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
        Sign up with Google
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group w-100">
      <button mat-button type="button" class="btn-facebook " (click)="authService.FacebookAuth()">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        Sign up with Facebook
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="divider w-100">
      <span class="bg-white p-3"><span class="orInner">OR</span></span>
    </div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="email" placeholder="email" formControlName="email" #userEmail>
    </mat-form-field>
    <!--Error codes-->
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <div class="form-group w-100">
        <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="w-100" (click)="emailValidate( userEmail.value)">Continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div *ngIf="regEmail">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" #userPwd required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="form-group w-100">
      <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="w-100"
        (click)="authService.SignUp( userEmail.value, userPwd.value)">Continue
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And a vague sense of how i should set up my `emailValidator` in ts

```
 emailValidate(email) {
    return this.authService.afAuth.auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
    .then(function(signInMethods) {
      //signInMethod returns ["password"] email not available
          if (signInMethods /*what to i put here */)
            //display verification error
            console.log(signInMethods);
      //signInMethod returns [] email available
      if (signInMethods /*what to i put here */)
      this.regEmail = email;
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if `signInMethods` contains the `password` so it will be something like

```
 emailValidate(email) {
    return this.authService.afAuth.auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
    .then((signInMethods)=> {
       var isEmailAvailable=!signInMethods.includes('password');
          if (isEmailAvailable){
               this.regEmail = email;
            }
             else{
           alert('email not available')
          }
    }
```

Comment: thank you this line was what got me stuck for so long `var isEmailAvailable=!signInMethods.includes('password');`